# CMS for sharing slides

Tags: cms, powerpoint, slideshow

I am looking for a CMS (content-management system) where users can upload, share, edit, copy, comment their powerpoint and keynote slides. Ideally, the slides should be viewable in the browser (possibly by converting the slides to HTML), and there should be a full text search functionality to search in the complete database of slides. There should also be functionality to rate, review, or comment / discuss on slides of other users.

Does anybody know of a CMS where this is possible? We would like to buy it and host it ourselves. Or do you know a service that offers this? We would be willing to pay for such a CMS or to use it as a service. Constraint is that it should be either hosted on premises or at least should be GDPR compliant and hosted in Europe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Odoo for this?  https://www.odoo.com/app/slides-features

There is a presentation tool module called Slides that lets you do all of this I think, with comments, and rating too.